# Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue

Tags: c#, winforms, json, json.net

I'm working on WinForms (C#) to find the ranks and keyword positions in Google and Bing. For this I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json.Net2.0.dll`. While I'm running the process it shows the error:

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.

How can I solve this problem?

```
public class GoogleSearch
{

    public int Search(string siteUrl, string searchExpression, ref string stage)
    {
        int position = 100;

        const string urlTemplate = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&safe=active&q={0}&start={1}";
        var resultsList = new List<SearchType>();
        int[] offsets = { 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48 };
        foreach (var offset in offsets)
        {
            var searchUrl = new Uri(string.Format(urlTemplate, searchExpression, offset));
            string page = new WebClient().DownloadString(searchUrl);
            JObject googleSearch = JObject.Parse(page);

            IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["responseData"]["results"].Children().ToList();//here i got the error ...

            IList<SearchType> searchResults = new List<SearchType>();


            foreach (JToken result in results)
            {
                SearchType searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchType>(result.ToString());
                resultsList.Add(searchResult);
            }
        }

        int i = 0;
        foreach (SearchType s in resultsList)
        {
            i = i + 1;
            if (s.Url.Contains(siteUrl))
            {
                position = i;
                return position;
            }
        }

        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us sample code and the JSON you're trying to parse.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving replay .... u mean can i paste the code here

Comment: @Victor: Yes. Otherwise we've got no chance of working out what you're doing wrong. A short but complete sample program (e.g. a console app) would be ideal.

Comment: this is i'm using to get position of keyword in google only..

Comment: @Victor: Please edit this information into your question, and also post the JSON you've got back, or a simplified version of it.

Comment: ok jon skeet i have modify the code and paast into my question...

Comment: @Victor: And the sample data? And where does it fail? What does `SearchType` look like?

Comment: from my code i have pass the parameters like url "www.google.come", searchdata is "search books" ref string is "search books"    " (IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["responseData"]["results"].Children().ToList();)//here i got the error ...

Comment: @Victor: Forget downloading anything - it would be helpful if you'd include code with hard-coded JSON (i.e. what you get in `page`). Obviously nothing after that line of code is relevant, so can be removed from the question. It would be helpful if you'd post a full stack trace though, which would give some information about which part of the line failed. You could also split that statement into several different ones - you're performing *lots* of operations in a single statement, which makes it harder to tell where the problem is.

Comment: ok thank you jon skeet i've try rectify this eorr if i get answer i'll tell you where i mistake in this code....and Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the NewtonSoft library trying to bind an object to non-existant properties. In the line

`SearchType searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchType>(result.ToString());`

the deserialization may be failing due to result containing properties that don't exist in SearchType.